# Every derived table must have its own alias mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join, alias

I have a temporary table named Days created as

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE days (start_date DATETIME)as
  SELECT DATE_ADD(begin_date, INTERVAL n - start_health_post_id DAY) as     
              start_date FROM NOF 
  ORDER BY n
  LIMIT nofdays;
```

Now I want to have a cross join with a bunch of select statements that perform inner join

So, I tried this ways

```
Select * from days
cross join
(
Select practices.*, providers.*, practice_locations.*
from practices
Inner Join providers on practices.health_post_id = providers.health_post_id
Inner join practice_locations on practices.health_post_id =practice_locations.health_post_id
);
```

But It gives an error saying , every derived table must have its own alias.

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an alias for your sub-query like:

```
Select * from days
cross join
(
Select practices.*, providers.*, practice_locations.*
from practices
Inner Join providers on practices.health_post_id = providers.health_post_id
Inner join practice_locations on practices.health_post_id =practice_locations.health_post_id
) t1;
```

I set t1 as alias.

Comment: What if I do another cross join, then where would you set the alias?

Comment: @Manutd After closing sub-query parentheses we can set a name as alias.

Comment: @Manutd my pleasure